# How can I print out two API results at once

Tags: javascript

I have identified two pieces of information from an API response that I want to print: data.points_of_interest[i].main_image (and) data.points_of_interest[i].title. I am able to print them out individually as shown in the code below;

```
var src = data.points_of_interest[i].main_image; // URL of the image
    var bodystuff = document.createElement('img');
    bodystuff.src=src;
    document.getElementById('outputs').appendChild(bodystuff);
    console.log(Image);
var name = data.points_of_interest[i].title;
    var bodystuff = document.createElement('p')
    bodystuff.innerHTML = name  
    document.getElementById('outputs').appendChild(bodystuff)
    console.log(name)
```

and here is my HTML;

```
<section  class="wrap" id="outputs"> 

</section>
```

I am trying to print them both in an instance, and have tried 'src.appendchild(name) and other combinations, but have not been successful at all any pointers?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "at once"?  You want to nest your image in a paragraph?

Comment: Yes or vice versa

Comment: You can't nest a paragraph into an image....

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question fully. You can an array of points of interest, each having a name and an image. Do you need to generalise/abstract the solution? In that case you need to create a function which takes a POI and use its two properties to create children for the POI (similar to the anonymous function provided by @Brad). A good, reusable approach is to create UI components (e.g. for POI) which accepts a POI object and returns HTML to represent that. Maybe add the expected HTML result on your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do what you want.  One way is to build all of the elements the way you want them, and append children as required.

https://jsfiddle.net/8154e4d1/

```
var outputSection = document.getElementById('outputs');
data.points_of_interest.forEach(function (poi) {
  var img = document.createElement('img')
  img.src = poi.main_image;

  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.textContent = poi.title;
  p.appendChild(img);

  outputSection.appendChild(p);
});
```

In this example, we create the image element first, and set its `src` to be the image URL.  Then we create the paragraph element which will contain the text as well as the image.  Next, we append the image to this paragraph.  Finally, we append the whole paragraph to the outer section.

If you find yourself doing a lot of this, you might consider switching to a JavaScript templating engine, such as [Swig](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig).  (There are many others to choose from as well.)

In case you decide to use jQuery, here's a simpler version:

https://jsfiddle.net/eemcpmys/1/

```
$('#outputs').append(
  data.points_of_interest.map(function (poi) {
    return $('<p>').append([
      poi.title,
      $('<img>').attr('src', poi.main_image)
    ]);
  })
);
```